# How would you display the file contents of file on a program in alphabetical order?

Tags: python

i know how to display them but not in aplhabetical order

```
if accessscores == "9x1" :
    f = open("9x1scores.csv", 'r')
    file_contents = f.read()
    print(file_contents)
    f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `sorted` built-in function. Also, use `.readlines()` to split lines individually.

```
if accessscores == "9x1" :
    f = open("9x1scores.csv", 'r')
    file_contents = f.readlines() # splits lines
    file_contents = sorted(file_contents)
    print(file_contents)
    f.close()
```